# How to get URL within content with JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am building an Application with PhoneGap which has a lot of `URLs` that are updated on a regular basis. Therefore I need to code a way to capture the `URL` and redirect it to the external browser. The InAppBrowser code is not the problem, I just can't seem to get the `URL`!
Here is what I have tried:

```
$('#page-content a').click(function(){
   currentPage = this.href.split('=')[1];
  window.open('currentPage', '_blank', 'location=yes')
});
```

No luck with the above. For one, I think the issue started with the `('=')`, as I thought that would be where to begin the split of the `href` from the `URL`

Here is a small section of the content that holds the URL I need to get:

```
    RSVP: from website<br />
Web: <a href="http://sites.ieee.org/scv-cas/">sites.ieee.org/scv-cas</a></p>
<p>
This is a review of the field of Digital Signal Processing (DSP) and is intended
for those who do not necessarily use DSP on a daily basis.
```

I am running PhoneGap 3.3 and JQuery 1.4

Edit: page content from my html page where I am adding the above content:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="page-title"></div>
    <div id="page-region"></div>
    <div id="page-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.href` is already the url, no need to split anything.

Comment: see this post [how to get the URL / URL parts](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/)

Comment: @elclanrs changed the code to this.href with no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can use `this.href` but `"currentPage" != currentPage`

Comment: @BahaaldineAzarmi The link seems to be what I am looking for. Although I am having trouble understanding how I can apply it. What is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split. Use `$(this).attr('href')` instead of `this.href.split('=')[1]`.
Should work just fine!

Updated answer:

Use this instead :

```
$('#page-content a').click(function(){
    currentPage = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(currentPage, '_blank', 'location=yes')
});
```

Actually the problem was that the variable currentPage was in quotes. I have changed    `window.open('currentPage', '_blank', 'location=yes')`to `window.open(currentPage, '_blank', 'location=yes')`.

If you don't want to use jquery then replace `$(this).attr('href')` by `this.href`.
Here's a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/R89LW/

Comment: I updated with you suggestion and I didn't get it to work. Any suggestions as to what else I could like at?

Comment: updated the answer. Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I implemented the above code and the console log does not have an output. So it must be an issue with getting the href click. Any recommendations?

Comment: Could it be because the href doesn't exist when the document is originally created? Since I am loading the content of the page when a user clicks maybe the script doesn't know it is there.

Comment: if the console log is returning nothing, it probably means that the 'a' tag is not there in the DOM when the click listener is getting added. You can check that and add the listener after you are sure that the anchor tag has been added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $('#page-content a').click(function () {
            currentPage = $(this).attr("href");
            window.open(currentPage, '_blank', 'location=yes')
        });
```

Comment: I gave it a try with no luck :/ This code seems spot on. Any idea what else could be causing a hang up?

Comment: I populate the #page-content with the text. I read that and the "a" in the $("#page-content a") targets the <a href> within the text. Is the right?

Comment: can you provide the entire html? because the parent tag of anchor is missing in your question

Comment: Ok, I added the html content. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I tested this in the function above: $('#page-title').html($(this).attr("href").toString()); to see if the event was even firing. It wasn't!

Comment: are you able to get the click event?? put an alert in it and test it.

Comment: Tested with an alert - no result.

Comment: is your anchor tag is in <div id="page-content"></div> ?

Comment: Yes, I am adding the description content to the #page-content. I populate the page with an array so the anchor tag is not there otherwise. That is why I can't pinpoint the URL.